# Is the set of 2-vectors having a zero in at least one coordinate a subspace of $\mathbf{R}^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Here is what I did:

1) ${V}*{0} = {[0,a]}*{0}={[0,0]}$

2) ${[0,a]}+{[0,b]} = {[0+0,(a+b)]}$

3) ${c[0,a]} = {[c*0,c*a]} = {[0,(c*a)]}$

So then this is subspace of $\mathbf{R}^2$ .

Is this correct?

Edited based on comment:

2) ${[a, 0] + [0,b]} = {[a+0,0+b]} = {[a,b]}$

Since the second condition fails it is not a subspace $\mathbf{R^2}$

Comment: Consider $[a,0]+[0,b]$

Comment: 2) ${[a, 0] + [0,b]} = {[a+0,0+b]} = {[a,b]}$ 
Since the second condition fails it is not a subspace $\mathbf{R^2}$

Comment: Is the answer to the problem correct now?

Comment: @EbrahimAHaji Yes.